# Using Tensorflow Graph Transformation Tools

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

When I try to use the graph transform tool with a FrozenGraph in Windows 10 through the Command Line, I always get the same error.
Code:

```
C://tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph ^
--in_graph=C://tensorflow-for-poets-2/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb ^
--out_graph=C://tensorflow-for-poets-2/new_optimized.pb ^
--inputs=Mul ^
--outputs=final_result ^
--transforms=' ^
   strip_unused_nodes ^
   fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) ^
   fold_batch_norms ^
   fold_old_batch_norms'
```

Error:

```
2018-07-27 14:59:09.303184: E tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph.cc:217] Unknown argument strip_unused_nodes.
usage: C://tensorflow/bazel- bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph
```

How should I proceed? I need to optimize this graph to run on tensorflowjs. It is a InceptionV3, so it is quite large for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown argument strip_unused_nodes

The error indicates that the arguments are missing to `strip_unused_nodes`. You need to specify the type and the shape your inputs are supposed to be. You can have a look at the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models#how_do_you_get_a_model_you_can_use_on_mobile)

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the problem is with the parsing of this script. When I use bash to execute them it works perfectly!